# How to add a configurable product to cart from the cart items?

Tags: cart, configurable-product, magento-1.6

I need to add configurable product to cart in observer. Problem is, I want to take the item from cart and add the same product to cart with different sku.

I tried the following code:

```
$itemOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
$addProductSku = 'Silky-#1-000';
                        $options = array(
                                'product' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($addProductSku),
                                'super_attribute' => $itemOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'],
                                'qty' => $item->getQty(),
                            );
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$addProductSku);
                        if ($product -> isSaleable()) {
                            $cart -> addProduct($product, $options);
                            $cart->save();
                            $session->setCartWasUpdated(true); // Not really necessary - Vicary

                        }
```

But it reports error as '

```
Invalid method Varien_Object::checkQtyIncrements(Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

'

Please anyone help on this?

Comment: This can't be the only error you're getting. Please include the full trace so we can see the file the error originates from

Answer (score 1):

Regardless what the error message is: What you try will not work.

You cannot add a different configurable product with the options from another configurable product. `super_attribute` uses the relation table between configurable and associated simple products and attributes.

Comment: Here For Me, I'm trying to add another configurable product which is same as the actual configurable product, Sku is the only difference for both.